# No boot menu after installing Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-7, menu

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7. During the installation I choose the *Something else* option and chose `/dev/sda` for the bootloader installation. The Ubuntu installation was successful, but I never got a boot menu from which I could choose the OS. What is the problem?

Comment: You should install GRUB bootloader to `/dev/sda` not `sda5`.

Comment: I infact first installed it to /dev/sda but got the same problem.

Comment: You can try booting from a live CD, `sudo mount --bind /boot <path to sda5>`, `sudo mount --bind / <path to sda3>` then issue `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`, finally `sudo update-grub2` and provide the output in your question.

Comment: What do you meant by Live CD?

Comment: It's the installation media from which you have installed Ubuntu. It can be a CD or an USB, just boot to it and the go to the `Try Ubuntu` option.

Comment: I just downloaded the Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit Iso and extracted the files in my USB(Bootable media). And I do get a TRY UBUNTU option. Does that means my USB is a Live CD?

Comment: Yes.  But you can call it a Live USB if you want.

Comment: So once I get into the "Try Ubuntu", what should I exactly do?

Comment: @AshishMahaur Actually, you can boot to a live session from any standard Ubuntu installation media, I presumed that you are working with a CD, so I called it live CD. After you get into a live session open a terminal by Ctrl+Alt+T and then issue commands from there.

Comment: Try the LTS edition, the LSD one gets too high sometimes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the terminal and run this command:

```
root@penreturns:~$ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Comment  line (add "#"):

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

It must look like this:

```
# GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

Update your GRUB with this comand:

```
root@penreturns:~$ sudo update-grub
```

Reboot your system and you will see how the system will now stop at the GRUB2 boot screen.

Enjoy!

http://penreturns.rc.my/2012/03/configure-grub2-menu-ubuntu.html