# No Grub and Can't Boot into Windows 8 After installing Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, boot, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

First, I installed Windows 8 in my desktop PC. (Not pre-installed... I did it by myself). Then I booted the Ubuntu dvd in UEFI mode (Did the same with Windows 8) and installed Ubuntu 12.10 64bit. Everything went perfectly. After rebooting, there's no grub! The system took me directly to Ubuntu! I can't log into Windows 8. Please help! Earlier, I used Boot Repair and it messd up with my Windows EFI files. So I was unable to boot Windows even after removing Ubuntu. I can't use boot repair. Now this is a new fresh install, Please tell me how to boot into both Windows 8 and Ubuntu!

Here is my /etc/defaults/grub :

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=1024×768
#GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1024×768

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Hi there, to have grub menu when booting, please follow this tutorial http://askubuntu.com/questions/152553/installed-ubuntu-12-04-lsd-alongside-with-windows-7-no-boot-menu

Comment: @penreturn Thanks! It brought back grub. But can't boot to Windows 8. I added it by following this guide http://askubuntu.com/questions/210914/grub-does-not-show-a-windows-8-option-after-dual-boot . Now grub gives an error when selecting windows 8 : error: file '/EFI/microsoft/BOOT/bootmgfw.efi' not found. But when checking, through Ubuntu, i can find that file

Comment: I suggest you refer this. http://askubuntu.com/questions/216215/invalid-efi-file-path . Scroll to bottom on the comment section.

Comment: @penreturn Thanks a lot! It helped! Shall I delete this question because the answer is already there. Or shall I add an answer combining all the answers into one.

Comment: I believe mods will take care about it. Enjoy Ubuntu!

Comment: @THpubs For '/EFI/microsoft/BOOT/bootmgfw.efi' not found, Please check the case, in my system to boot win7, it's chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

Run Boot-Repair --> `Advanced Options` --> tick `Restore EFI backups` --> `Apply` , and indicate the new URL that will appear. Reboot, you should get back access to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed Windows 8 Pro to an extra hard drive on my PC. My system which runs Ubuntu primarily and boots up through GRUB couldn't seem to find the new OS after I installed it. So I searched and read all of these solutions involving manually re-configuring GRUB system files, uninstalling and re-installing Windows, etc. All of these are terrible solutions. The best solution is so, so easy. All you have to do is run this update command for GRUB from a terminal window within your Linux distro:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

It searches your hard drives for new kernels and OSs. Problem Solved. Enjoy!