# Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04 (Windows will not load - Loops prepairing to repair windows) Asus ROG G750JW

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I have windows 8 on my first drive which is 1 TB and Ubuntu on the secondary drive which is 500 GB. I attempted installing grub2 and updating. (See pictures below to see partitions)

I followed this and now I can't get into windows at all. 
[No Grub and Can't Boot into Windows 8 After installing Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270222/no-grub-and-cant-boot-into-windows-8-after-installing-ubuntu-12-10)

Can someone give me a walk through to fix this mess? Last time I used ubuntu dual boot was 2010. I'm prepairing a usb iso of ubuntu as several tutorials suggest I can fix it with a live usb. But they are for older distros and i'm not sure it will work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I just got grub working again after window 8.1 disabled grub. Read the attach links here. http://askubuntu.com/questions/491425/grub-not-working-after-windows-8-1-update-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/492778#492778

Comment: In boot-repair > advance options > Grub options make sure secure boot is disabled. HTH